# WSO2 API-M cannot consume API created in a tenant

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm facing one problem in using **WSO2 API Manager**:
I can't consume an API created in a tenant.
Scenario:
 We have deployed wso2 api manager in a server, **all in one**, version **2.6.0** in a server with Oracle Linux 7, and all ok.
We aren't using port offset, neither installed analytics nor identity server.
Creating and consuming APIs **without tenants was working fine**.
Now we created two tenants in this server: abc.com and 123.com .
At Management Console in abc.com I defined 123.com as external store.
We logged in API Publisher, in **tenant abc.com and created API ApiTeste**, we published it to external store 123.com, no errors.
After we logged at API Store, in tenant **abc.com (same where API was created)**, we subscribed to API but when we try consume this API, got errors.
Could someone help me with this problem?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.
Gislaine

**EXTERNAL STORE DEFINITION**(removed tags just for facilitate visualization):
StoreURL: http://myhostapis.apis.com:9763/store
ExternalAPIStore: id="123COM" type="wso2" 
className="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.publishers.WSO2APIPublisher"
DisplayName: 123Com
Endpoint: http://myhostapis.apis.com:9763/store
Username: admin@123.com
Password: xxxxxxxx

Followed link [1] to define external store, but didn't find other  cases using tenants:
[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Publish+to+multiple+external+API+stores

LOG ERRORS:

> TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-19 08:30:46,348] ERROR
>   {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} -  **The service cannot be found
>   for the endpoint reference (EPR)**  {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine}
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the
>   endpoint reference (EPR)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.validateTransport(DispatchPhase.java:251)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.checkPostConditions(DispatchPhase.java:109)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:329)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:263)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-19 08:30:46,350] ERROR
>   {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker} -  Fault
>   processing response message through Axis2
>   {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker}
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the
>   endpoint reference (EPR)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.validateTransport(DispatchPhase.java:251)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.checkPostConditions(DispatchPhase.java:109)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:329)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:263)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-19 08:30:54,343]  INFO
>   {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  STATUS =
>   Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 101504, ERROR_MESSAGE
>   = Send timeout {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}

Comment: Despite this error, we can see the backend error responds.

Comment: TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-19 08:30:46,345] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-2 << Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-19 08:30:46,345] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-2 << X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}

Comment: TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-19 08:30:46,345] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-2 << Set-Cookie: CM=12; path=/ {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-19 08:30:46,345] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-2 << Set-Cookie: DHUR=19062019083046; path=/ {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-19 08:30:46,345] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-2 << X-Powered-By: ASP.NET {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}

Comment: TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-19 08:30:46,345] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-2 << Date: Wed, 19 Jun 2019 11:30:46 GMT {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-19 08:30:46,345] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-2 << Content-Length: 374 {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-19 08:30:46,348] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} -  The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR)  {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine}

Comment: I tried the above scenario in a fresh pack, it seems to work. according to the error printed it seems like there is a timeout. It could be that the response hasn't been sent from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

@dushansilva, thanks. I updated my wso2 api-m server and now I can create and consume APIs in their respective tenants.